# Displaying images and navbar on certain urls react

Tags: reactjs

Im using a react app and have done the login and signup forms and have private routes in app.js. Everyone has access to login and sign up. The rest of the pages are protected. I have the landing signup page rendering a background image using HTML tag in css but I cant get it to switch to another image in another component. Also I dont want the navbar to show up on login and Signup pages.

```
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute path="/user/home" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/user/resources" component={Resources} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/user/about" component={About} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/user/mealplan" component={MealPlan} />
       

          <Route exact path="/" component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Navbar component named something like NavBarController. While calling the navbar controller component pass in the "Type" as prop. Type should be a state and should change depending on the page the user is on.

```
<NavBarController type={1}></NavBarController>
```

You would just create a few different NavBars and then NavBarController will handle whichever navbar you want to display out of your multiple navbars.

Your NavBarController will return something like this:

```
return (props.type===1?<NavBarHome/>
:props.type===2?<NavBarResources/>
:props.type===3?<NavBarAbout/>
:props.type===4?<NavBarMealPlan/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the current pathname is the pathname , you want to hide your nav or other component , follow the below code :

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// custom hook to get the current pathname in React

  const location = useLocation();
  
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute path="/user/home" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/user/resources" component={Resources} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/user/about" component={About} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/user/mealplan" component={MealPlan} />

          {location.pathname!=="some pathname"&& <Route exact path="/" component={SignUp} /> }
          {location.pathname!=="some pathname"&& <Route path="/login" component={Login} /> }
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
```